How to Check , find and Manage this error "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details"
How to Check , find and Manage this error "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details".

You can use exceptional handling to know the root cause like below:
public ActionResult Add(DemoData demoData)  
{  
    try  
    {  
         //your existing code
    }  
    catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)  
    { 
        foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)  
        {  
            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)  
            {  
                string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",  
                    validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),  
                    validationError.ErrorMessage);  
            }  
        }  
    }  
} 

